# Counting the number of unival subtrees in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I recently came across this interview question of finding the number of unival subtrees in a binary tree. How can this be done?

Comment: A quick google search.

Comment: what "unival" stands for?

Comment: @avim unival stands for univalue. That means all nodes in the tree are the same value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the time complexity of counting the number of all structurally different binary trees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535472/what-would-be-the-time-complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-all-structurally-dif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int countUniVals(node* head, bool* unival) {
    if (!node) {
        *unival = true;
        return 0;
    }
    bool uniL,uniR;
    int sum = countUniVals(head->l, &uniL) + countUniVals(head->r, &uniR);
    if (uniL && uniR &&
        (!head->l || head->l->val == head->val) && 
        (!head->r || head->r->val == head->val)) {
        sum++;
        *unival = true;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean "Universal value sub trees" - [see the description here](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnicholasworkshop.com%2Fpost%2Finterview-practice-extra-07-universal-value-binary-tree%2F&ei=cW4HVbmWOsXN8gX8r4G4Aw&usg=AFQjCNE4fXer05AsvCdSBMGsr2xUKOouag&bvm=bv.88198703,d.dGc)

In which case you would just implement a traversal of the tree whereby for each node if all its children are equal to the parent then add 1 (as you have identified a universal value tree)